# "Iterator not incrementable" while deleting an item from std::vector

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, visual-studio-2015, sdl

I'm currently developing a game using SDL2 along with C++.

My character shoots bullets and of course when one of them hits an enemy it has to be deleted from the std::vector he is in.

My vector of bullets is declared as follows

```
std::vector<Bullet> _bullets;
```

and when I try to delete one from it I do the following

```
void Player::DestroyBullet(Bullet b)
{
    for (auto it = _bullets.begin(); it != _bullets.end();)
    {
        if ((*it).GetId() == b.GetId())
        {
            it = _bullets.erase(it);
        }
        else
        {
            ++it;
        }
    }
}
```

The problem now is that while erasing that bullet, the compiler gives me an assertion fail which says "Expression: vector iterator not incrementable".

I searched some different solutions to delete an item from a vector (using iterators, using pop_back mixed with some other functions) but none of them worked. This vector is of course used by other functions in the game loop (drawing function which continuously iterates through it to draw the bullets textures and update function which takes care of all the logic).

May these functions raise this problem? It would be strange, because they use (of course) different iterators for their loops, so they should not care about this.

P.S. I am programming with Visual Studio 2015.

EDIT 1: The application is **NOT** multi-threaded.

EDIT 2: It's a bit late but I found out months ago that on GCC this problem does not exist. It only occurs on Visual CPP compiler.

Comment: Are you using multiple threads? If so, reading and updating *at the same time* will give you all kinds of problems. The vector has to be in a consistent state after each operation, but not *during*.

Comment: On which statement are you getting "vector iterator not incrementable"?

Comment: This part of code is OK, you must have madea  a mistake elsewhere

Comment: Probably a multithread problem, the error you are describing occurs when iterator is invalidated, it can happen if another thread places/removes elements to/from this vector.

Comment: Say `it` is pointing to the third element of `_bullets` when it enters `else` and before `++it` is executed, the third element is deleted from some where else.Then `++it` is executed.Boom.

Comment: @BoPersson nope, I am not using multiple threads. Thanks anyways for the tip! That is true!

Comment: Can you try to show an example to reproduce this problem? Though I do not install VS2015, I don't think it will complain on the current code you show (otherwise it would be a trivial bug of VS2015).

Answer (score 0):

you should use `::std::remove_if` instead:

```
_bullets.erase
(
    ::std::remove_if
    (
        _bullets.begin()
    ,   _bullets.end()
    ,   [&b](Bullet const & bullet)
        {
            return (bullet.GetId() == b.GetId());
        }
    )
,   _bullets.end()
);
```

Comment: @UmNyobe `remove_if` should be preferred anyway since it is faster.

Comment: Really? It's probably faster if you remove more than one element, but it's not clear that actually happens in this case.

Comment: @VTT I tried your code but it still gives me the same problem (I also had to remove `const` from `(Bullet const & bullet)` as it was not compiling). This is  really a headache for me, cannot figure out why. Here follows a link to a screenshot of the assertion fail window, maybe it can help! [link](http://prntscr.com/gadtjk)

Comment: @stack_overflower If this code does not compile with `const` then it is probably because `GetId` method is not const-qualified for some reason. And you should add information on which exact statement you are getting this assertion, probably with a stack trace. Also this assertion fail messages are coming from running executable, not from a compiler.

Comment: @VTT I can't get any stack trace from VS for this fail, I can only see that in the output window there is the same text of the screenshot I linked before. I'm sorry, maybe I just don't know how to gather useful information when an assertion is raised this way. Is there any setting in VS to get more infos when assert fails happen?

Comment: @VTT Ok, I'm definitely blind, it clearly says "press Retry to debug application". I'm gonna do that and search for something useful, I'll keep you guys updated.